# Adjust delay for activating Full Screen Mode toolbar

Tags: macos, fullscreen

Is it possible to change the delay on the full screen mode window toolbar in OS X Yosemite?

I'm thinking of something like this, but for the toolbar

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 5
```

I love using full screen mode, but I'm frequently accidentally triggering the toolbar which covers up whatever I'm trying to access at the top of the screen.

Comment: From my search on the `defaults domains`I've found nothing regarding the Menu/Tool bar. As explained here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/252515/79808

Comment: `defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide-delay -float 0.05 && killall Dock` -float = time

Comment: Interesting : https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Resize-relocate-remove-or-delay-Toolbar-in-Fullscreen-mode/td-p/1299072

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
defaults write -g NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.001
```

or

```
defaults delete -g NSWindowResizeTime
```

to revert it.  Taken from http://www.defaults-write.com/disable-full-screen-animation-of-os-x/.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect for me. Is there somer reset that needs to happen after the command?

Comment: @JesseSchoff try $ killall Finder from the Terminal/command-line ..

Comment: Isn't the question a different question - i.e. waiting 5 seconds before activating?