# Change delay for auto-hide on menu bar

Tags: menu-bar, macos

In 10.11 is there a way to change the delay for showing the menu bar when auto-hide is enabled? I know for the dock you could use terminal and `defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -int 0`

Comment: Looks like it's hardly possible:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204415/making-the-auto-hidden-menu-bar-show-up-faster

Answer (score 5):

I ran the following Terminal command `defaults find Menu Bar` and found this:

`Found 1 keys in domain 'Apple Global Domain': {
    "_HIHideMenuBar" = 0;
}`

The `_HIHideMenuBar`property can be either 0 for *Disabled* or 1 for *Enabled*. And that's the same setting found in *System Preferences - General - Automatically hide and show the menu bar*.

So I guess it isn't possible as of today.

Answer (score 2):

As of macOS Sierra 10.12.6 there is no preference for controlling the animation speed of the menubar hiding animation. It used to be there, but was removed in Yosemite. The only workaround is to press `Ctrl-Fn-F2` (or `Ctrl-F2` if you inverted the Fn key) to immediately show and activate the menu bar. You can then navigate by keyboard or click items with the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and enter the following:

```
defaults write "Apple Global Domain" com.apple.springing.delay -int 0
```

Then logout and log back in.

Comment: This doesn’t work in Yosemite or newer.

Comment: No effect in Monterey