# How to change the time until the menu bar shows in fullscreen mode

Tags: menu-bar, fullscreen

Is there a way to increase the delay until the menu bar shows when the mouse pointer touches the top of the screen when in Full Screen view?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but have a look at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208393/change-delay-for-auto-hide-on-menu-bar/260396#260396

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks, but none of those solutions work in Big Sur.